# Angular 9 : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accesToken')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am trying to read access token from JSON file. here from `child component` I am calling to `MapReportConfigModel` class. Inside the class I applied `getMapConfig()` method. using that method I am getting JSON data.

```
childComponent --> MapReportConfigModel
                   --> getMapConfig()   ---> mapReportConfig[json file]
```

### JSON file

```
{
  "accessToken": "123",
}
```

### MapReportConfigModel

```
export class MapReportConfigModel {
  accesToken: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getMapConfig(): Observable<MapReportConfigModel> {
    let mapConfigData = `config/mapReportConfig.json`;
    return this.httpClient.get<MapReportConfigModel>(mapConfigData);
  }
}
```

### LoadMap method in child component

```
configData: MapReportConfigModel;
  map!: mapboxgl.Map;

   loadMap(): void {
    this.mapReportConfigModel
      .getMapConfig()
      .subscribe(configData => this.configData = configData);
    mapboxgl!.accessToken = this.configData.accesToken;
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: this.configData.style,
      zoom: this.configData.zoom
    });
```

ERROR :

when I tried to get the token I got this error message : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accesToken')`

1. So my question is this way correct?
2. If this way is incorrect how can I get data from json file.(if you can explain with code it would be better)
3. if is way is correct, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be great if you provide a code where you declared `mapboxgl`

Comment: Hi. I have updated the Load Map method. could you please check the my question again. Here style and zoom details also coming from JSON file.

Comment: @DmitryS. did you find the reason ?